# SqLite - Intermitted Connection Issue

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, outlook-addin

This is a weird one.

I'm using System.Data.Sqlite version 1.0.112 from Nuget.

I'm working on a VTSO plugin for Outlook

Randomly, despite my connection string remaining the same the application will occasionally load in the database.DB in from the bin/debug folder for the FIRST connection to the database, and then any subsequent connection it will load the Database.DB file in from 'My Documents'

My SQLite connection all follow the same structure as below:

```
    public static DataTable GetUnsynchedTimeEntries()
    {

        DataTable dt;



        string cs = @"URI=file:" + dbPath;

        Log.Debug("Opening SQLite Database:"+cs);

        using (var con = new SQLiteConnection(cs))
        {
            Log.Debug("ConnectionString:"+con.ConnectionString);


            string selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM TIME_ENTRIES";
            using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(selectSQL, con))
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                SQLiteDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                dt = new DataTable("TIME_ENTRIES");
                dt.Load(dataReader);
                dataReader.Close();

            }
        }

        return dt;

    }
```

The dbPath value is set as a public static string dbPath on the class and does not change, its not a fully qualified path, just a filename, as I always want the application to create and use a Sqlite file in the folder relative to install where the application is running.

Does Sqlite have some sort of fallback to [My Documents] if it encounters a problem and doesnt shout up?

Comment: What happens if you use an absolute path `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirctory`. you'll get consistent results with this, even if the working directory changes.

Comment: I ended up doing this and it prevented the issue from reoccurring.  Thanka